# Custom Android Lockscreen with integrated lock

Tags: android

I own a Samsung phone and I'm thoroughly annoyed by the fact that using a pattern unlock automatically disables all lock-screen widgets. I'd like to have more than just the time when I turn on my screen, but I also value the security of my phone.

I looked for apps with integrated pattern unlocks, and found GO Locker, but it's really basic and doesn't offer much customisation. So I turn to you for software that can satisfy the following features:

- Possibly, but not necessarily, free
- Offers a good deal of **customisability**
- Has an **integrated pattern unlock**
- Shows **phone, SMS, and music** notifications/widgets to some degree
- Does not require you to install a launcher with it (I use my own custom launcher)
- Can be for rooted phones only

Comment: What version of android do you have? Stock android 4.2+ includes all of this. Stock android lets you still have all your lock screen widgets even with a pattern unlock.

Comment: 4.2.2. I did mention owning a *Samsung* phone, hence the issue

Comment: You also said you could root the phone, which makes me wonder why you dont install stock android and remove samsung touchwiz

Comment: At the time I didn't want to risk a brand new phone to a whole reimaging. In retrospect, I'm glad I didn't because despite its annoyances the Samsung ROM offers some benefits. And I don't think there's a way to only change the lock screen back to stock, is there?

Comment: No. You would have to re-image the whole phone. I don't know of any solutions other than NILS Lockscreen widget, but its buggy with pattern unlocks

Comment: @Humdinger I'll have a look at the app anyway. Eventually I will sit down and make a list of pros and cons of now flashing the kitkat ROM to my phone, considering it's been a while and that I might be able to find replacements for the nice features Samsung offers. I know it's a little off-topic, but without knowing my specific needs, would you personally suggest reimaging?

Comment: I have never used samsung touch wiz. So I wouldnt really know the tradeoffs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started using **[C Locker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.ccs.lockscreen)**, which pretty much offers everything you're asking for. Let me list some of the things I think match your request:

- **Free:** There's a [C Locker Free](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.ccs.lockscreen) with minor limitations (not affecting any of the features you're after IMHO), and there's [C Locker Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.ccs.lockscreen_pro) with some advanced features added (and the ads removed, which in the free version are visible in the configuration screens only)
- **Offers a good deal of customisability:** If not that, then what? The "C" stands for "Customizable" (and for "Convenient"). Tons of features, like including weather, clock, and more on the lock screen, customizing the "unlock wheel" (unlock-and-start-app), and I love the "light-bulb" symbol in that wheel to quickly turn on the torch when needed.
- **Has an integrated pattern unlock:** Want it always? Or only for certain shortcuts? Or for all but X? Up to you, just configure it :) (must admit, I didn't try this part yet)
- **Shows phone, SMS, and music notifications/widgets to some degree:** No degree. All you want. Well, almost. I currently can directly start two camera apps, the flash light, mail, telephone, and have 3 more left I didn't use yet. Has multiple lock screens which *switch automatically* (context sensitive): You have your normal lockscreen ("Standard"). As soon as you start music, the "Music Lock" is used (with the player widget). You even can have multiple location-based screens: one for the office, one for home, whatever you set up.
- **Does not require you to install a launcher with it:** Didn't ask me for that. Still using my custom launcher (Apex)
- **Can be for rooted phones only:** Not really required, but if your phone is rooted, it supports some extra features – such as making it a system app

Disadvantages? Minor so far. I've used the free version for a day, then straight went to buy the pro. Turning the screen on, it took several seconds for the lock-screen to show up its controls. So I've made it a system app. Still takes a little (maybe 3 secs), but got a little faster.

All in all: I don't think another locker can come up with that. So: top five, recommendation :)

Finally, some "visuals":

[image: C Locker Music] [image: C Locker] [image: The Lock Ring]
<sup>*C Locker:* Music controls, a custom lock-screen, the "unlock wheel" (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

In case you wonder: the "wheel" you see in the third screenshot is, by default, invisible – and shows up as soon as you press-and-hold the "locker" symbol in its center (and then draw it to the action you want to perform). But as almost everything with this app, that's (C)ustomizable :)

Oh, PS: In the "about" section, Cheah (the dev) links to a lot of helpful youtube tutorials showing your tips and tricks to get more out of the app…

Apart from that, I just "scratched the surface". Lots of other things I didn't mention, like gesture control, one/two/three times tapping a widget, and more. Just check it out, there's a free version!

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much for the recommendation; if the software is as good as you made it sound, I'll be more than satisfied. Have a virtual **+1** for the extensive review, given my currently insufficient rep.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is! As I wrote I mean it: the only "not-so-nice" thingy so far is the delay after switching on the screen. But hey, that gives us "a little rest" on a hectic day. I'm absolutely willing to pay those "3 secs" for the comfort it gives. And I'm sure Cheah will do his best to fix even that :) Just the fact that I bought it straight ahead after just one day should speak for itself :) I'm sure you'll enjoy it! Then, please don't forget to "accept" the answer :) (tick the check-mark next to it)

Comment: I was waiting to install the lockscreen app before irreversibly accepting your answer, but it sounds like something that will happen in the near future :) About those 3 seconds, during that time does the screen show the launcher behind it, and can the user interact with it?

Comment: 1) accepting is reversible, you can "unaccept" any time (especially in case a "better answer" appears later, which I doubt ;) 2) it shows a blank screen. But depending on your configuration, you can access the notification bar even with the screen locked. Showing the launcher behind would somehow defeat the purpose of a lock-screen ;)

Comment: @LS97 I'll +1 for you, great answer!